# Trigger ISPConfig vhost folders creation

Tags: php, mysql, scripting, apache2, bind

I make an script that fill up all ISPConfig tables by itself and now i only need to raise some script to create the needed vhost and the rest of the symblink needed for apache to work.

My Script is working like a charm since i can view all the data correctly using the ISPConfig frontend.

Digging into the ISPConfig panel i see a RaiseEvent function triggered everytime a record is created but i can't trace where it ends and how it perform the creation of the symblink.

Maybe calling some function or cron it can work.

I'm using Apache 2 + PHP 5.3 + MySQL + ISPConfig 3 on Ubuntu Server 10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I respond myself.

Since version 3 ISPConfig came with a simple API that let you performe some operation like Adding FTP Users, Websites and Databases.

I left here an example of how to create a database:

```
$params_db = array(
                    'server_id'         => '1',
                    'system_user'       => "web10",
                    'system_group'      => 'client0',
                    'active'            => 'y',

                    'type' => 'mysql',
                    'database_name' => $NAME,
                    'database_user' => $NAME,
                    'database_password' => '123456',
                    'database_charset' => 'utf8',
                    'remote_access' => 'n',
                    );
```

Next we have to create on the ISPConfig panel a "remote user" that allow to comunicate using the webservice.

```
$soap_username = 'whatever';
$soap_password = 'h4ck3m3';
$soap_location = 'http://localhost:8080/remote/index.php';
$soap_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/remote/';
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => $soap_location, 'uri' => $soap_uri));
```

So, what's next?

Next we call the webserver function like this:

```
try
{

  //* Login to the remote server

  if( $session_id = $client->login($soap_username,$soap_password))
  {
      echo 'Logged into remote server sucessfully. The SessionID is '.$session_id. "\n";

      $client->sites_database_add($session_id, $client_id, $params_db);

      //* Logout
      if($client->logout($session_id))
      {
        echo "DB Created\n";
      }
  }
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
  die('SOAP Error: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

For more information check out this link of howtogeek website: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-create-remote-api-scripts-for-ispconfig-3